# Android Studio needs to sync with gradle after running app again and again

Tags: android, android-studio

Every time when I run my app, all ids in the project are gone, it shows error for all ids as "Cannot resolve symbol 'relativeLayoutParent'". I need to "Sync Project with Gradle files" to get everything to a normal position. I need to do this every time when I hit the "Run app". I am facing this issue for a single project only.

**I have tried:**

- Deleted .gradle
- Clean project and build again
- Invalidate Caches and restart

It's a very huge project containing so many flavors, it's impossible for me to create a new project.

Comment: Once you sync the gradle, next time before running enable "gradle offline". Give this a try.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: Well then need to check exact issue.                                                                             1. Check if you have any update for Android Studio and any dependencies you have added. Update those, then do Invalidate Caches & restart AS.                                                                                                      2. Try building & running app through command line.